# ipinfodb lookup returns countryCode 'RD'

Tags: javascript, geocode

I am calling ipinfodb via JS.  Recently I have had around 5-6 responses (from around 600) that specify the countryCode as 'RD'.

'RD' isn't a ccTLD and I cannot find any reason for this to be returned.  Has anybody had a similar issue and did you find a fix?

I am calling ipinfodb on the route

```
http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=_apikey_&ip=_ip_
```

Comment: Hi,

Can you please advice which IP address is producing the RD as results?

We have been using [IPInfoDB.com][1] for years and does not have the results in our records.


  [1]: http://www.IPInfoDB.com

Comment: Sorry Michael, we have not seen this since Dec '12..  I have checked our audit log but I don't have any transactions for the affected users that I can match an IP too. I recall that when we investigated the IP addresses mapped to reasonable ISPs in the States, Europe and North England?  Sorry that I am unable to provide more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RD` is returned as a pseudo-country code for reserved IP addresses.

This includes things like private addresses, class D and E networks (IPv4) and loopback.

For a complete list of addresses that will return this value, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).

I can't actually find this behaviour documented anywhere, but experimentation easily demonstrates that this is the case, and moreover the `<CountryName>` element is populated with the word "Reserved" in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

RD is a short country code for "RESERVED" IP address range. It is a range reserved for certain networking purpose as approved by IETF.

This code is only used in IPInfoDB version 2 which has been deprecated.

You should upgrade to latest version 3 API which is constantly updated.

In v3, you will only see "-" in the country code results to avoid this confusion.